# With setTimeOut, why it console 4, 5 times ? javascript

Tags: javascript

If I run this code then it console 4 at 5 time, can anyone explain why it is happening ?

```
let number = 1;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  number=i;
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(number)
  },1000)
}
```

Also if I modify this to as below then output is 5 times 5 ?

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(i)
   },1000)
 }
```

And why it prints 0 to 4 when we use let like

```
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(i)
   },1000)
 }
```

Comment: you've discovered that `let` and `var` scoping rules are different - `why it prints 0 to 5` no, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Its a typical use case of `var` being functional scope ,every iteration of for loop shares the same value of var (doesn't creates a new scope as var being functional scope) which is kind of global in here

so when the last condition arrives `i<5` i is  already has become 4 ,and  it is shared by every callback of setTimeout so they all prints 4 ,4 times

But in case of let a new scope is formed in every iteration ,as let being a block scope `(for loop has a block scope)`